# Bootstrap row отображается на другом row. Как исправить?

Tags: bootstrap, internet-explorer, css

У меня 4 row. 3 row стоят друг под другом, автоматически. Но 4-ый row сидит на третьем! Margin-bottom, margin-top не помогают, т.к при изменении размера окна блок смещается вверх вниз. Даже position: relative; ставил. Тож смещается. Код тот же, как и в трех предыдущих:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
```

Но он почему то сидит на третьем row. Не подскажете, как исправить? Кстати данная проблема в Internet Explorer 8

**UPDATE**

```
clear:both;
display: block;
```

не помогли.

Comment: кто поможет?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю для IE8 нужно написать свой клас с маргином.

```
<div class="row-fluid ie8"></div>
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <style>.ie8 {margin-top:*some px*}</style>    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: я же сказал, смещается тогда при изменении размера окна. Повнимательнее читайте